# I am unable to install : sudo apt get update and also sudo apt-get update, kind of similar issues i suspect, but I am not sure

Tags: apt, updates, repository

I cannot add all the result cause there are a lot of links...

```
  404  Not Found [IP: 200.236.31.4 80]
Ign:109 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe arm64 Packages
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/pypa/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm64'
```

And for sudo apt-get update:

```
...
Ign:109 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe arm64 Packages
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/pypa/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm64'
```

Comment: Please edit the question and post the whole terminal output. Then, press `Ctrl+K` to format it as code. Once it is formatted as code, it can still contain many links.

Comment: Can you try restoring the default sources.list using GUI? https://askubuntu.com/a/192388/124466

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using the Wine repository, but have an ARM processor, which the repository does not support.

So, open `Software & Updates`, and remove that repository in the list of `Other Software`.

Also, you there is a warning due to the pypy PPA, and [it does support](https://launchpad.net/%7Estefanor/+archive/ubuntu/pypy/+build/25433432) your version of Ubuntu for ARM. Try removing that PPA, and add the PPA once again.

Run the command

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:pypy/ppa
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pypy/ppa
```

Comment: So I removed the Wine repository and when I try to run the commands you gave me it still gives me this errors : E: Failed to fetch http://c.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]

Comment: E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: C@AndreiNitui Can you please edit the question instead of writing these in comments? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1468957/i-am-unable-to-install-sudo-apt-get-update-and-also-sudo-apt-get-update-kind/1468958?noredirect=1#